# MySql for React-Native cross platform app & website

Tags: mysql, react-native

I want to build a website and app the will need to create, read, write, update and delete records in a mysql db. How can I have my React-Native app accomplish this? The db is server-side as in I can't use async or local storage on the app.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use fetch on your servers API to make CRUD requests.

This may require some re-writing or adding to the backend, such that some of it takes data and returns data, as opposed to returning something the browser can render.

I would highly recommend this tutorial series, granted it goes over building an API specifically for the app and doesn't discuss web stuff.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzQWIQOqeUSNX_ZDqt9L3TMSwFa9GbIwp

Comment: Thanks! I took a look at the tutorial and saw that he's using MongoDB. Would Fetch work with CRUD operations using mySql?

Comment: Yeah, it's similar. The API can be different, but it can also be the same if you use something like Sequelize. I'd appreciate if you chose my answe as the correct answer btw. : )

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to use MongoDb but I've heard it can be buggy and records have been known to go missing. Since I'll be storing credit cards and other personal info I don't want to take chances.

Comment: You can always move over, MongoDB is good for getting something setup quickly and database code shouldn't be too tricky.